# On Error - Using loop that won't be interrupted irregardless of the error

Tags: excel, for-loop, onerror, vba

I made a code that will use the cells in column A and search it in a website and pull down a certain table I need. However, sometimes I get an error (because the name is wrong or whatever), and I want the code to skip it and move on.

Example: if searched A3 was a problem, and I want the code to search A4, etc.

The Error is Run-time error '91': object variable or With block variable not set

Code:

```
Sub SearchBot()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer 
Dim aEle As HTMLLinkElement 
Dim y As Integer 
Dim result As String 
Dim tbl As Object, obj_tbl As Object
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim start_time As Date
Dim end_time As Date
Dim cookie As String
Dim result_cookie As String

Set objIE = New InternetExplorer  

objIE.Visible = True  

objIE.navigate "https://website.com" 

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 

For i = 2 To 1829


objIE.document.getElementById("SearchTopBar").Value = _
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value  '

Set oNode = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("iPadHack tmbsearchright"
(0) 
oNode.Click

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 

Dim tblEle As Object
Set tblEle = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("cTblListBody")(5) 

Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = tblEle.innerText
Debug.Print tblEle.innerText

Next

ErrorHandler

Resume Next

objIE.Quit 
End Sub
```

Comment: When you step through the code, is it actually hitting your ErrorHandler?

Comment: It is not. It won't let me start the code saying: compile error: sub or function not defined

Comment: I suspect it might be the reference for using IE isnt turned on.

3rd dot point https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264506%28v=vs.60%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If you're getting a Compile Error, how are you able to identify the Runtime error?  What is your actual problem? Compliation, or runtime?

Comment: If I take out the code below, the code works. I would then get error 91. The reason for this is because sometimes the website that I'm using doesn't recognize the name that is being searched.                            
                                                                                                                  "On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Error Handler

    Resume Next"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can raise an error:

```
Set tblEle = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("cTblListBody")(5)
```

For example, if no matching element with classname "cTblListBody" is found, or if there are fewer than 6 of those items found, etc. In this case, your error handler will take over, and the `tblEle` will be `Nothing`.

This statement `Resume Next` will attempt to resume execution on the *next line* (from the line which raised the error), and these lines will of course fail if the `tblEle` has not been assigned (i.e., `Is Nothing`).

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = tblEle.innerText
Debug.Print tblEle.innerText
```

You don't want to `Resume Next`, you want to resume at the next iteration of the loop, so you can do this with another label:

```
On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 

    Dim tblEle As Object
    Set tblEle = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("cTblListBody")(5) 

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = tblEle.innerText
    Debug.Print tblEle.innerText

NextItem:
Next

ErrorHandler

Resume NextItem
```

Or, more appropriately (IMHO), trap this error:

```
'## THIS LINE IS NOT NEEDED: 
' On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop 

    Dim tblEle As Object
    Set tblEle = objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("cTblListBody")
    If Not tblEle Is Nothing Then
        If tblEle.length > 5 Then
            Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value = tblEle(5).innerText
            Debug.Print tblEle(5).innerText
        End If
    End If
Next

'## THESE ARE NOT NEEDED:
'ErrorHandler
'Resume NextItem
```

Note: this assumes that at least 6 `cTblListBody` are found, if that may not be the case, additional logic may be required.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
Dim objIE As Object

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objIE.Top = 0
    objIE.Left = 0
    objIE.Width = 800
    objIE.Height = 600
    objIE.Visible = True
```